# Meta properties from Create-React-App index.html file not reflected in Google Search

Tags: reactjs, meta-tags, react-helmet

I included the `react-helmet-async` package to include meta tags for every page. Helmet works on the website, but when I search on google using the keywords or even typing "safety garage door", which is included in the description, I can't find my website on google.

I typed `site:safetygaragedoor.com` on google and it shows me a description "Web site created using create-react-app". Any help?

Here is the `<head>` tag inside my `index.html` file:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="We are safety garage door and we have been in garage door business since 2018, we are here to provide good quality and quick service at reasonable price that fit everybody's budget. We value each and every one of our customers. We strive to go above and beyond to ensure full client satisfaction." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Safety garage door, Garage door repair, rokstar garage door, Garage Door spring replacement, Garage Door broken coil, Garage door Broken spring, Garage Door installation, Garage door opener, Garage door sensors, Garage door repair">
    <meta name="author" content="Sufian Hamdan">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>Safety Garage Door</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

To address your first point

> I typed site:safetygaragedoor.com on google and it shows me a description "Web site created using create-react-app"

You don't have `"Web site created using create-react-app"` anywhere in your `<head>` component which leads me to believe that Google likely indexed your page before you made changes to the `index.html` file.

There's no immediate fix besides asking Google to re-crawl your site at the following url:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/ask-google-to-recrawl

If you're also using `react-helmet` anywhere in your site Google is usually unaware of those meta tags because they are not present in the initial `index.html` file when Googlebot requests a page.

`react-helmet` adds meta tags to the head of the webpage once the javascript of the page is loaded and the react content is fully built. Googlebot doesn't always run the javascript of your site and will most likely index it from the initial `index.html` file.

One such solution to that problem using the create-react-app framework is having a pre-rendering service that serves a fully built version of the webpage to crawlers like Googlebot.

If you're using a service like Netlify.com they usually provide their own pre-rendering feature (https://docs.netlify.com/site-deploys/post-processing/prerendering/)

If you're hosting your site on your own server you might need to use a service like [prerender.io](https://prerender.io)

Comment: That actually makes sense now, yes I made the changes after google indexing my website, and yes my website is on Netlify.com I will try their own pre-rendering feature and see if that works.

Answer (score -1):

To deal with SEO problems in React you can refer here

https://javascript.plainenglish.io/3-easy-ways-to-solve-seo-problems-in-react-applications-d3d7873dc494

The short answer is what you are experiencing is not a problem. In fact that's how it works. You have to use NextJS in order to have a proper  SEO

Comment: Do I have to recreate my website in NextJS ? i actually forgot to mention that my website is just a static website there are no APIs included or anything.

Comment: I just thought why not creating it using ReactJs then this happened to me, I didn't know that ReactJS have this issue.

Comment: If you want better SEO then yes you have to recreate. But the good news is NextJS is exactly like React so there should be very minimum overhead